# Logging memory allocation functions using DLL injection

Tags: c, linker, dynamic-linking, dll-injection

I have a simple program let's call it a *victim*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int *a = malloc(200);
    printf("%p\n", a);
}
```

And I want to inject a shared object into this program that will log all the calls to the `malloc` function. So it will works like a memory logger:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *
malloc(size_t n)
{
    static void * (*real_malloc)(size_t) = NULL;

    if (real_malloc == NULL) {
        real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");

        if (real_malloc == NULL) {
#if 0
            printf("MEMORY FILTER: can't find the real malloc() function: %s\n", dlerror());
#endif
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    void *result = real_malloc(n);

#if 0
    if (result != NULL)
        printf("MEMORY FILTER: allocated %zu bytes at address %p.\n", n, result);
    else
        printf("MEMORY FILTER: failed to allocate %zu bytes.\n", n);
#endif

    return result;
}
```

And then I run the victim as follows:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. LD_PRELOAD=libmemlog.so ./victim
0x55e0747792a0
```

It works fine but when I uncomment `#if 0 ... #endif` blocks when the `printf` function is called then I get a segmentation fault. This is happens because `printf` calls `malloc` inside itself and we got an endless recursion which eventually crushes.

How can I get logging work in this case?

Comment: Have you tried catching the crash in a debugger (or enable core-file generation that you can use after the crash)? Perhaps `printf` (or one of the functions called while appending to the output buffer) allocates memory through `malloc`? What happens if your `main` function calls `printf` *before* its `malloc` call?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, it crashes if just call `printf` in `main`. Yeah I've tried to catch the crash in GDB, but I am not really good in it, so I am still in the debugger.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thanks for the hints, I understood why I get segfault (I've updated the question). So here is another question: how to get the logging work?

Comment: You need to write your own formatting function which doesn't use malloc. Then you can log using the [`write`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) system interface. (`write` doesn't use the memory allocation library).

Comment: Or, you could set a thread-local flag to indicate that this is a recursive call, and not print when it's a recursive call. (then you won't log the malloc calls inside printf)

Comment: @user253751, hmm, but how can I determine that the current call is recursive?

Comment: `is_recursive = true; printf(stuff); is_recursive = false;`

Comment: @user253751, oh it was so simple. Thank you very much for help! Can you post the answer? I will accept it.

Comment: @rici, thank you for the help, too. Appreciate it.